# Cramer's model and the Riemann hypothesis

Tags: probability, number-theory, probability-distributions, prime-numbers

Recall Cramer's model for prime number distribution:

We have a sequence of countable, independent Bernoulli random variables $X_n$ with parameter $p_n = 1/\log n$ (the probability of $n$ being prime). For a positive real number $x$, define $S_x = \sum_{n\leq x}X_n$.

I have seen it claimed in many places (for instance, [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/cramers-random-model/)) that, almost surely:

$$S_x = x/\log x + O(x^{1/2+\epsilon}).$$

I guess it shouldn't be too hard to prove this and I tried showing this using the Chebyshev bound but couldn't. How do you prove such a result?

Comment: Does this equation assume the Riemann hypothesis ? If not, you should delete  it from the title.

Comment: The equation does not assume the Riemann hypothesis but $S_x$ is modelling the number of primes less than $x$ and what I want to prove is the Riemann hypothesis (under the probabilistic model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $X_n-\frac1{\log n}$ are independent random variables with zero-mean and variance $$\Bbb{E}[(X_n-\frac1{\log n})^2]=(1-\frac1{\log n}) (1-\frac1{\log n})^2+ \frac1{\log n} (0-\frac1{\log n})^2\le 2$$
Thus the variance of $$Y_x=\sum_{n\le x}(X_n-\frac1{\log n})$$ is $$\Bbb{E}[Y_x]=\sum_{n\le x}\Bbb{E}[(X_n-\frac1{\log n})^2]\le 2x$$ If there is $r > 0$ and a sequence $x_k\to \infty$ such that $$Pr(Y_{x_k} > x_k^{1/2+\epsilon})\ge r$$ then $$\forall k, \qquad \Bbb{E}[Y_{x_k}^2] \ge  r x_k^{1+2\epsilon}$$ which is a contradiction.

> Whence there is no such sequence $x_k$ and the probability that $\lim_{x\to \infty} Y_{x} x^{-1/2-\epsilon}= 0$ is $1$.

Comment: This answer could be made more precise by invoking Chebyshev's inequality.